Merge XML File of robotframework
Using cmd I am able to merge robot generated xml file, but I have to merge more than 500 files I am able to merge 500 robot files, How to merge it?
I am merging xml file by using command rebot --merge. It is working fine but I have to merge more than 500 files.

When you say It is working fine. how many XML outputs did you tried?
How is the name of the files? Maybe you should have shown us, what is your command.

is it a python question or cmd?
